# how to optimize magento 1.9.X website?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, optimization

buddy:

I have a Magento 1.9.1 version website, I feel it running slower, how to do it can make it run faster?

I hope you help!

thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Follow these tips below on how to speed up Magento and keep it running fast to ensure return shoppers and sales.

Speed Up Magento Index

- Latest Version
- Content Delivery Network
- Utilize Caching
- Enable Flat Catalog
- Image Optimization
- Concatenate (merge) CSS and Javascript Files
- Enable Magento Compilation
- Clean Up Magento Database & Logs
- Fewer Extensions & Modules
- MySQL Configuration
- Update Indexes
- PHP Accelerators
- Choose Fast Web Hosting

For more information follow the below link:

- https://www.keycdn.com/blog/speed-up-magento/
- https://www.appseconnect.com/speed-up-your-magento-store-from-slow-to-insanely-fast/
- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-website-performance-optimization-tips/

Answer (score 3):

You can use tools like "https://gtmetrix.com" to check why your website is slow. And based on suggestion  you can make neccesary changes.

Some common things which help in magento site optimization are below

**From magento admin**

-Enable JS and CSS merge and minification

-Enable cache

-Enable full page cache(FPC)

-Enable flat catalog

-Enable compilation

**Some other points.**

-Enable gzip compression

-Avoid bad request URL

-Compress images

-Clean up database and log on regular interval

-Better hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

If your site is so slow it depends on several things, firstly you have to check your custom code that you have added, If you don't develop with the right way and the best practices you will definitely have a slowdown performance, **exemple** if you do an `load in a foreach` or any loop, if you don't limit the `select Collection`, dont `optimized loops`, don't have optimized `js css`, `disable cache` etc ... see also if you have recently added some extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons which cause the website speed. Check following points:

1. Merge CSS and JS
2. Enable Cache
3. Enable Flat tables for category and products.
4. Enable Magento Compilation.

These are in Magento admin and you can easily achieve.

If all these points are already achieved, then, next stage of optimization is:

1. Use CDN (Content Delivery Network)
2. Optimize image as much as possible.
3. Try to remove unwanted JS and CSS from the website.
4. Enable gzip compression (web server configuration)
5. Check logs created on the website and minimize it as much as possible.
6. Avoid bad request (404 errors)

After achieving this it is recommended to use any cache management tool like **varnish, Redis, Memcached**. This tools definitely improve speed a lot.

If you again feel that there is still need to improve speed then check database calling in Magento. Check the use of getModel, getCollection in for loop and try to minimize as much as possible. For example inplace of "getModel" try to use "getResourceModel".

There are many tools which help you to understand the problem on the website like:

1. https://gtmetrix.com/
2. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/
3. [Aoe-profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler) (install and check which database call takes time)
4. [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/)
5. [magento-debug](https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug)

Answer (score 0):

Using  GTmetrix you can solve your site performance.
please visit this site for speed up you website.

[Click here for optimize website](https://gtmetrix.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do to speed up Magento 1.9.x:

1. **Extensions audit**. Disable your custom extensions one by one and see which one slows you down the most. At the core of every slow Magento in 99% cases lies a poorly coded 3rd-party extension.
2. **Webpagetest.org**. This site will show you performance waterfall. See what requests took the most time and fix them. It might be big images, external javascript files etc.

Audit your custom extensions first. You probably have one of those slow modules installed.