# speed optimization of magento sites

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, pagespeed

what are the key spots to focus on to optimized the loading speed of a magento 1 and 2 websites without using specific premium extensions,
Aside from reducing image sizes.

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186059/how-to-optimize-magento-1-9-x-website/186061#186061

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: please use search, there are lots of answers already

Comment: MagenX.. thank you for the comment but mine is pretty specific and the technology and custom scripts to use presently has evolved which makes this very relevant